# Get TLS working in local development between react-scripts and a node api server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, https

I have set up and installed my self signed certificate for my local development environment. I have react-scripts running my frontend. I have set the **HTTPS=true** environment variable and I use a 'prestart' script in my package.json to write my self signed certificate to ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl/server.pem.

```
"prestart": "(cat ./certs/server.crt ./certs/server.key > ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl/server.pem) || :",
```

So when I hit https://localhost:3000 (the webpack-dev-server) I get a secure and trusted lock. All great so far.

My API server is written in node and runs on localhost:4000. I am using express and https module with the key and cert properties pointing to the same self signed certificate and key file.

```
const app = express();
const httpsServer = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/server.crt')
}, app);
module.exports = httpsServer;
```

When I hit https://localhost:4000/login via fetch from my react app, I get the following error in the browser console: (and of course the request doesn't go through)

**OPTIONS https://localhost:4000/login net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH**

I have been looking at cipher suite mismatches along with many other things but nothing seems to fix it. 
Is there a problem with the same certificate being used for both the node server and the web-dev-server, even though they are on the same host?

Any help would be much appreciated and I am fully aware that there is probably something very straight forward that I have missed , so apologies up front for having gone slightly code blind.

Comment: I don't have an answer that will solve your issue, but I went through your issue as well. Although I can't remember what fixed it, I can say that your use of the same cert and key for both UI and backend services should be fine as I am doing the same thing as you and it's working fine. I wrote up what I'm doing in the following link, the only difference is I'm using a signed certificate instead of self-signed. It's dead easy so worth trying. https://www.chrismacpherson.net/dev/easy-tls-react-development-environment/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible problems:

1. Private keys requires passphrase (It's not applicable, because works with dev-server)
2. Keys are not encoded as UTF-8, and you need to ensure with `fs.readFileSync('%key or cert%', 'utf-8')`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but the encoding option doesn't seem to change anything